# How to configure xml of layout for preventing word cutting?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have problems with word cutting at XML, look at the picture below:
[image]

As you can see word `Delete` is cut. Below is my layout for this part:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="30"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/more_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="@color/gray_light"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pict_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_more"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="More"
                android:layout_below="@id/pict_1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/archive"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pict_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_inbox"
                android:contentDescription="TODO" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Archive"
                android:layout_below="@id/pict_2"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pict_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_delete"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_below="@id/pict_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Delete"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

In general I noticed that it is caused by padding which pull elements inside parent layout. I tried to change it, but I see that word `Archive` is also can be influenced. How I can solve this problem with wrong layout xml?

Comment: In the last **RelativeLayout** you take extra 5 dp. Middle **RelativeLayout** has 5dp but Last one has 10 dp. For first one **More** has 4 character but Last one **Delete** has six character. So now compare **Archive** 7 characters with 5 dp padding .

Comment: @TariqulIslam, right now I see that I have 10-5-10 padding at my layout

Answer (score 1):

add you third layout(delete) with wrap content and weight like below

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pict_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_delete"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@id/pict_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```